# tikz example from manual fails

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

I have copied an example from the tikz manual, but it fails to compile

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{circuits}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.IEC}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=-90,
                circuit ee IEC,
                x=3.25cm,y=2.25cm,semithick,
                every info/.style={font=\footnotesize},
                small circuit symbols,
                set resistor graphic=var resistor IEC graphic,
                set diode graphic=var diode IEC graphic,
                set make contact graphic= var make contact IEC graphic]
% Let us start with some contacts:
\foreach \contact/\y in {1/1,2/2,3/3.5,4/4.5,5/5.5}
{
  \node [contact] (left contact \contact) at (0,\y) {};
  \node [contact] (right contact \contact) at (1,\y) {};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Some samples of the errors messages:

> Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/circuit ee IEC'
>
> Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/set resistor graphic'

Comment: Try adding the circuits.ee.IEC library (hope I remember correctly I don't have the manual right now).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a small error in the documentation. The documentation says

```
\usetikzlibrary{circuit.ee.IEC}
```

but you need

```
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
```

(missing s)

Than the example works